# How can I export my data from Cloudant for analytics purposes?

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

I have a NodeJS app using a Cloudant DB. We need to extract all the data from Cloudant into another form of storage to do some analytics on it. What is the best way to export all my data from Cloudant?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on where you want to export the data to, and what sort of data you have.

[couchbackup](https://github.com/cloudant/couchbackup) is a backup tool that saves your data in a format that allows it to be easily restored into another Cloudant or CouchDB database.

[couchimport](https://github.com/glynnbird/couchimport) has a `couchexport` command which dumps the data into a csv file. From there it can be imported into multiple other databases, like MySQL, Postgres or sqlite. This tool works best for data that is relatively flat, i.e. does not contain a lot of nested objects.

There is also a [kafka connector](https://github.com/IBM/cloudant-kafka-connector/), which allows you to pipe your data into any other data sink that is supported by kafka.